# switchMap is not cancelling previous HTTP call

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, switchmap

one of angular service method(http call) created with switchMap operator,so it can reject/cancel the previous rest API calls if new one arrived. it is working fine and make a backend call but it not reject any BE call but it sequentially calling every call and wait for all of BE call to response, it should reject previous calls.

where I am doing wrong ?

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-switchmap-merge-results-multiple-http-reque-yyq7sn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

to create first observer event I am using from() method and by each typing it calls HTTP get API.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're calling `updateSearch()` on every key press which means you're creating many chains that run in parallel instead of making a single chain that can unsubscribe the `switchMap`ed Observable:

You achieve what you need with for example Subject:

```
s = new Subject();

s.pipe(
  switchMap(y => {
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").pipe(
      delay(2000),
      map(z => {
        return z;
      })
    );
  ));

updateSearch(value) {
  s.next(value);
}
```

Comment: thank you @martin, actually i want  updateSearch() to return z value to component. any way to do it?

Comment: as per your answer @martin  s.next(value); method will return void, but i want  updateSearch() to return response of HTTP call.